# Cannot reinitialise DataTable al volver a realizar una búsqueda

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

Tengo un datatable que realiza una búsqueda a la base de datos mandando como parámetros el mes y el año. La búsqueda me funciona bien, el problema está en que al momento de realizar otra búsqueda me lanza el siguiente mensaje:

> Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Sé que esto sucede porque la tabla ya está llena y por lo tanto debo destruir la anterior antes de generar una nueva. El problema está en que aunque me realiza la búsqueda como deseo, me sigue arrojando el mismo error antes de mostrar los nuevos datos.

Este es mi código:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".buscar_man", function () {
        $("#lisManu").dataTable().fnDestroy();
         var meses = $("#meses").val();
         var year = $("#year").val();

 var dt_for = $('#lisManu').dataTable({    
        'autoWidth': false,
        'processing': true,
        'paging': true,
        'pagingType': 'full_numbers',
        'serverSide': true,
        'scrollX': true,
        'bFilter': false,
        'language': {
        'url': base_url + 'public/json/language.spanish.json'
        },
     "columnDefs": [
             // Personalizar algunas celdas
            {// Celda de ID no visible
                 "targets": [19],
                 "visible": false,
                 "searchable": false
             },
             {// Celda de ID no visible
                 "targets": [20],
                 "visible": false,
                 "searchable": false
             },
             {
              "targets":[0],
              "visible": false,
              "searchable": false
             },
             {// Crear celda adicional para botones de ver, editar y eliminar
                 "targets": [1],
                 "data": null,
                 "width": '135px',
                 "defaultContent": '<div align="center"></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" title="Editar datos" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs fa fa-refresh edit_dat_for"></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" title="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs fa fa-trash eli_dat_for"></a></a></div>'
             },

        ],
    "ajax": {
        'type': 'POST',
        'url': 'reportes_manual/bus_mes_year',
        'data': {
           meses: meses,
           year: year,
           
        },
    }

});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu mismo te has contestado, no debes de crear la tabla mas de una vez.

Debes de jugar con los datos de la tabla no con la tabla.

Te paso un ejemplo:

https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Si te ves muy apurado pon tu `.dataTables()` en un bloque `try`

Comment: Puedo simplemente destruir el datatable y me crea el datatable con la nueva búsqueda pero el error me sigue apareciendo, de la manera en que esta reflejada en ese ejemplo no me ha servido mucho, puesto que lo que necesito que al parecer no aclare bien, es que al buscar se borre los datos anteriores y solo muestre la nueva búsqueda.

Comment: Pero al escribir algo en el textbox de busqueda el framework ya te hace desaparecer los elementos que no coinciden.

Comment: con `miTabla.rows().data();` obtienes los datos que se han filtrado de la busqueda.

Comment: mmm ahora veo que no especifique que no estoy usando el buscador del framework si no uno aparte que yo cree dos text area uno para año y otro para mes porque los datos los traigo con una función desde base de datos

Comment: tal vez pido mucho, pero seria posible un `https://jsfiddle.net/`, por que el problema puede esta en cualquier lado. Yo ya tuve mis pelea hace tiempo con el datatable

Comment: Entonces lo que debes hacer es un reload del datatables. Y para ello debes actualizar el URL que obtiene la data con los nuevos valores de tus textbox que no forman parte del filtro del datatables